# I use np.reshape and put this "no attribute 'reshape' for". What happens?

Tags: python, reshape

I am trying to make this code but every time I run the code it gives me this error:

no attribute 'reshape' for

```
aa= np.random.randint(2,5)
x=np.arange(100,200+1)
x = tuple[pow(i, aa) for i in x]
A=x.reshape(10,10)
det=np.linalg.det(A)
```

I do not know exactly what this error means.

Comment: `x` isn't an array, therefore you can't use reshape...

Comment: And I would have to do to make it array because I put np.array does not run the code to me either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `x` to an array, not a tuple (your current tuple syntax is invalid). Since `np.array` is a function, you need to enclose the argument in parentheses. If you want `x` to have length 100, you also need to adjust your range indices.

```
aa= np.random.randint(2,5)
x=np.arange(100,200)
x = np.array([pow(i, aa) for i in x])
A=x.reshape(10,10)
det=np.linalg.det(A)
```

An easier way:

```
x = np.power(x,aa)
```

Comment: Strange, this code works for me... I changed the 201 to 200 so that the reshaping can be done.

Comment: Never mind. My mistake. Misunderstood what arange is doing and thought it was passing dimensions.